# In Elixir why concat binary to the beginning of the long binary takes way long time than concat to the end

Tags: binary, elixir

```
ExUnit.start
ExUnit.configure trace: true

defmodule Foo do
  def bar(0, acc), do: acc
  def bar(n, acc), do: bar(n - 1, acc <> "1")

  def baz(0, acc),  do: acc
  def baz(n, acc),  do: baz(n - 1, "1" <> acc)
end

defmodule Test do
  use ExUnit.Case

  @num 1_000_000

  test ~s(acc <> "1") do
      Foo.bar(@num, "")
  end

  test ~s("1" <> acc) do
      Foo.baz(@num, "")
  end
end
```

Result

```
Test
  * test acc <> "1" (42.1ms)
  * test "1" <> acc (35733.3ms)
```

Why concat `"1"` to the beginning of the long binary `acc` takes way long time than concat to the end?

Comment: Not *at all* specific to elixir. You'd have this behavior with literally anything (that wasn't deoptimized to *always* do it the slow way).

Comment: http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/binaryhandling.html explains the reason in detail (search for "append" on the page). I'll try to summarize in an answer later (unless someone beats me to it).

Comment: Heh. Read "concat to a binary" to mean you were performing binary patching, thus amenable to a language or tool independent response.

Comment: @Dogbert thanks for the link! Would be appreciate an answer in Elixir context.